# function is being placed wrong

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to test a function by placing it in a div. I've first created a testfunction which just return a random string. This i'm trying to show in a div in the resultfunction. It shows the string however it shows it at the top of the page instead of in the div? How can i fix this

**functions:**

```
function testfunction() {
    return "lol";
}


function resultpage() {



    $output = '';


            $output .= '<ul id="nav">';
       $output .= ' <li><a href="#part-1">League of Legends</a></li>';
        $output .= '<li><a href="#part-2">CS:GO</a></li>';
        $output .= '<li><a href="#part-3">Dota2</a></li>';
        $output .= '<li><a href="#part-3">Hearthstone</a></li>';
    $output .= '</ul>';
    $output .= '<div id="content">';
        $output .= '<div id="part-1">';

        echo testfunction();


        $output .= '</div>';
       $output .= ' <div id="part-2">';
       $output .= '     Ma deuxième partie';
       $output .= ' </div>';
       $output .= ' <div id="part-3">';
       $output .= '     Ma troisième partie';
       $output .= ' </div>';
    $output .= '</div>';




return $output;
}
add_shortcode('resultpage', 'resultpage');
```

Comment: `$output .= testfunction();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you echo instead of adding it to string

```
    $output .= '<div id="part-1">';

    echo testfunction()
```

change this to

```
   $output .= '<div id="part-1">';

   $output .= testfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening in that function is line by line, some html gets concatenated into a variable, in the amidst of all this, an echo to a function is happening (so it is displayed immediately), then you can continue concatenating to that variable, and after the function finishes running, you echo out $output

To fix it, simply

```
$output .= testfunction();
```